# How does observable and promise work in Angular?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I bit unclear about the *Observable* and *Promise*. I'd like to explain briefly below taking an example of displaying the count of user registrations for a website over a period of time.

**Scenario 1** 
@ Minute 1: HTTP GET makes an API call and fetches all 50 records at the first minute

**Scenario 2** 
@ Minute 2: HTTP GET makes another API call and fetches all 100 records at the second minute

*Observable emits multiple values over a period of time*

Does the above sentence mean that **Scenario 1** is enough to get all the records (i.e., 100 registrations) to compute the registration count. Once we make an API call, will it listens for the continues responses from the back-end until we cancel all the subscriptions from the subscribers?

What does this **over a period of time** mean?

*Promise emits a single value*

Does this mean when we use promise, we get all records at that specific time of call.
For instance: 50 records at minute 1 and 100 records at minute 2 @ second call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a diagram that is worth a thousand words:

```
Single   |  Function | Promise
---------|-----------|----------------
Multiple |  Iterator | Observable
---------|-----------|----------------
         |   Sync    |  Async
         |  (Pull)   |  (Push)
```

**Pull** - the **consumer decides** when the **data** from the **producer** will be sent
**Push** - the **producer decides** when the **data** will be **sent to** the **consumer**

Think of an **Observable** as a newsletter. It is enough the **subscribe** to the newsletter **once** and you'll keep on receiving notifications whenever new content is available - *Observable emits multiple values over a period of time*.

```js
const newsletterProducer = new Subject();
const newsletter$ = newsletterProducer.asObservable();

// It is enough to subscribe only once
newsletter$.subscribe(console.log);

newsletterProducer.next('JS article of the week #1');

// After some time...
timer(1000)
    .subscribe(() => newsletterProducer.next('JS article of the week #2'))
```

In your Angular app, the **consumers** could be your **smart components**. They would subscribe to the observables which can be found inside a data service.

---

When dealing with **promises**, on the other hand, you'd have to explicitly ask for the content every time you want to receive it - *Promise emits a single value*.

```js
const getMovies = genre => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, genre + Math.random()));

const actionMoviesPromise = getMovies('action');

actionMoviesPromise.then(m => console.log('#1 ' + m)); // #1 action0.35095072611888156
actionMoviesPromise.then(m => console.log('#2 ' + m)); // #2 action0.35095072611888156
actionMoviesPromise.then(m => console.log('#3 ' + m)); // #3 action0.35095072611888156


const horrorMoviesPromise = getMovies('horror');

horrorMoviesPromise.then(m => console.log('#1 ' + m)); // #1 horror0.7990946657868658
horrorMoviesPromise.then(m => console.log('#2 ' + m)); // #2 horror0.7990946657868658
horrorMoviesPromise.then(m => console.log('#3 ' + m)); // #3 horror0.7990946657868658
```

As you can see, if you want to get movies by a another genre, you'd have to create another promise for that and **manually** call `then`. Conversely, when using **Observables**, all the **consumer** has to do is to **subscribe** to the **producer**. Then, whenever the producer emits new data, the consumer will simply receive it.

Comment: *Observable emits multiple values over a period of time* - Does this holds good over HTTP calls as well? For instance- single call API call and keep on receive data overtime?

Comment: That holds true if you’re using web sockets, where you keep the connection open after the request is made. Also, bear in mind that the produced values over time might come from http calls, DOM events, user input etc.

Answer (score 2):

***Over a period of time*** means with `Observables` you can easily control the emission of values. You can do everything with `Observables` that a `Promise` can do but it has some superpowers also.

Let's take an example and try to understand what is ***Over a period of time*** :

```
import { of, interval } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';


const source = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(5)
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(`Value emitted after ${x} seconds`));
```

Please refer to this [stackblitz console](https://rxjs-qefvpm.stackblitz.io) for the above code. You could see the values 0,1,2,3,4 getting logged by one second delay and then completes.

With `Promises` we won't be able to achieve this(emitting 0,1,2,3,4) with a time span of 5 seconds. The above [stackblitz console](https://rxjs-qefvpm.stackblitz.io) has a `promise` value logging also. It emits ***one*** value with the full array.

Coming to your 2nd question `Once we make an API call, will it listens for the continues responses from the back-end until we cancel all the subscriptions from the subscribers?`
The answer is ***NO***.

For `pagination` implementation you can refer to this [link](https://blog.bouzekri.net/2016-05-15-angular2-rxjs-simple-paginated-list-with-search-field.html)